# Why are Python Enums slow?

Tags: performance, python-3.x, enums

Today I tried to outsource some of my "final" values (members of my class) from a class to an Enum. I ran the unittests I wrote and noticed, that the tests needed much longer to complete than before. When I put these "final" values back into the class, everything was back to old speed again. Here an example of how I accessed them when they were in the Enum:

```
class SpecialCharacters(Enum):

    TONE_NUMBERS = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

Accessing it like this:

```
SpecialCharacters.TONE_NUMBERS.value
```

Example of accessing the values when they are in the class:

```
self.TONE_NUMBERS
```

So I wonder why my tests take 3x (!) as much time when I put the values in the Enum. It should be a simple call to another class' members, but that wouldn't make such a big difference I guess.

(The goal of outsourcing them was that they're available for other classes and those other classes don't have to access a class with which they have nothing to do.)

My python version is 3.4.

Comment: How many times are you accessing these values in your tests? Millions? Tens of millions? The more dereferencing steps are required, the slower it's going to be. But it should not be a noticeable amount, unless you are accessing these very, very, very often.

Comment: The dereferencing shouldn't influence the factor with which I have to multiply to get the longer runtime, because it's always the same way of accessing the values und that dereferencing is unlikely to consume so much time, that dereferencing is 2 times as long as the actual algorithm.

Comment: @Zephir, Enum class is for plain values primarily as seen from the examples in [the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), not for arrays?

Comment: See also https://bugs.python.org/issue39102

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known bug in Python 3.4's enum: https://bugs.python.org/issue23486

It's been "fixed" in Python 3.5, such that enum attribute lookup is only 3x slower than normal, instead of 20x.

Comment: Well that's a significant improvement. 3x the time is still something, but I don't have a comparison with other programming languages for this matter, so it might be common.

Answer (score 7):

To answer the question `Why?`:

The original design for `Enum` was to have members be virtual attributes.  This means they were not kept in the `Enum` class dictionary, which meant that every lookup possible had to first fail, after which `__getattr__` would be called on the class and the member found.

So basically lots of busy work.

The fix was to put the members in the class dictionary when possible (which is most of the time).

Comment: Unfortunately big `IntFlag` enums are extremely slow in combining attributes - I thought of using them instead of frozensets (reduce memory) but or'ing a few hundred int flags takes a *lot* of time when an IntFlag has ~10k members. Maybe related to https://bugs.python.org/issue39102 ? Thanks for the enum module anyway :)

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: Hopefully that will be faster in 3.10, but I will admit I wasn't considering a flag set with thousands of possible values.  What are you modelling?

Comment: Well I have an algorith that uses dictionaries of sets of ints as the base data stuctures - so checks membership and then performs unions and intersections. Extending to bigger datasets the sets take an awful lot of memory - some of it cause equal sets are different objects. As I think that unions and intersections should be fast with flags and they are singletons I gave it a whirl - mapping the ints to `range(1, num_keys + 1)` and creating an IntFlag for each of those indexes. Or'ing those (which would be the intersection) takes ages for num_keys ~ 10k